Publishing Under Pseudonym/Future Name?
I am currently in the process of getting my legal name changed (It's a bit of a process since I'm usually outside of my home state) and though I'm not looking to publish anytime soon, if I do publish before getting my name legally changed, would it be possible to publish under my future name? I'm not seeking anonymity or anything, I'm mostly just trying to avoid my academic history becoming disorganized because of this.

related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44213/if-you-change-your-name-while-doing-research-can-you-list-both-names-on-a-publi

related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63849/separating-academic-identity-from-social-identity

Please see the linked questions, which should provide sufficient info. The short answer is; yes it is possible (and practiced by some) to publish under a different name than the one (currently) on your documents.

It is often the other way round - that people keep publishing under their old name, because they already have some publications under this name, or that they adopt a double name for their publications: e.g., somebody who has published as Olivia Newton, but became Olivia John, may publish now as Olivia Newton-John.
Some journals help associating the publications by the same person under different name, or simply link to ORCID - but this depends on the area research.
E.g., Physical Review name change policy:

Name Change Policy
APS allows authors who have published research in the Physical Review journals to alter or update their published names and/or personal pronouns for any reason. These changes will be made to the electronic and PDF versions of all published papers in the Physical Review journals requested by the author. In most cases, authors can request changes to papers published as far back as the year 2000. Names in the reference list can also be changed, provided those articles have already been updated. See APS Name Change Policy. Name changes and metadata corrections are reflected in Cross Mark, indexing services, and Google scholar.

